# Iptables Log Output Cleaning

Tags: android, linux, grep, iptables, cut

I am trying to minimize the iptables log , but I don't know how. I read some tutorials about grep,cut and awk. But still I can't do nothing useful. I would like to achieve a result like `SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=192.168.1.2 PROTO=TCP SYN`.

This is how 2 packets from the original log look like:

```
 <4>[1133131.431453] [IPT IN START] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=08:60:6e:a5:bc:0b:00:16:cf:b9:08:2c:08:00:45:00:00:2c:51:56:00:00:3
    8:06:ae:1d:c0:a8:01:06:c0:a8:01:02:f8:a4:08:01:f2:0e:30:9c:00:00:00:00:60:02:04:00:ed:7c:00:00:02:04:05:b4:00:00:00:00:0
    0:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=20822 PROTO=TCP SPT=63652 DPT=2049 WINDOW
    =1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   

 <4>[1133131.440239] [IPT IN START] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=08:60:6e:a5:bc:0b:00:16:cf:b9:08:2c:08:00:45:00:00:2c:48:6d:00:00:3
    4:06:bb:06:c0:a8:01:06:c0:a8:01:02:f8:a4:04:42:f2:0e:30:9c:00:00:00:00:60:02:04:00:f1:3b:00:00:02:04:05:b4:00:00:00:00:0
    0:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=18541 PROTO=TCP SPT=63652 DPT=1090 WINDOW
    =1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

This is what I've tried: `fgrep '[IPT IN ' /proc/kmsg |cut -d" " -f1-4,9,13,14,21,22,23,26`

And that was the result:

```
<4>[1132271.745701] [IPT IN START] DST=192.168.1.2 TTL=45 ID=30608
<4>[1132271.747764] [IPT IN START] DST=192.168.1.2 TTL=54 ID=63992
<4>[1132271.751983] [IPT IN START] DST=192.168.1.2 TTL=52 ID=4162
```

Btw , I tried few more options , but this one was the only one which returned some results.

Thanks in advance.

p.s Those are iptables_arm , I am experimenting with my tablet. I am trying to read those results from my android program in order to capture portscan launched from my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

i would have just used awk and counted the whitespace separated columns i want:

> grep "IPT IN" /proc/kmsg | awk '{print $1 $2 $xy1 $xy2 $xy3}'

the xy1,2,3 parts have to be replaced by the specific number of the column you want ;-)

Comment: **grep 'IPT IN' /proc/kmsg |awk '{print $8,$9,$15,$17}'** 
Works perfectly.. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I do create a simple log-file in real time, here is how to do it:

```
tail --follow=name /var/log/yourLogfile | awk '{print $8,$9,$15,$17 | "tee /var/log/newlog"}' &
```

This creates a new log file `/var/log/newlog` with data you like to have in it.